# How do I change the Javascript injected into PDFs by IBM Maximo's "Direct Print" feature?

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, printing, maximo

**Background**

When a user in IBM Maximo utilizes the Direct Print or Direct Print with Attachments feature for a report, Maximo creates a PDF with the output of the report and with injected JavaScript to make the reader send it to the user's default printer. However, the reader is popping up a dialog, asking the user if they want to allow the document to print itself, and the users are annoyed because they already said they wanted this thing printed.

So far, the best solution I have found for this problem is on an [acrobatusers](https://acrobatusers.com/forum/javascript/document-trying-print-dialog-reader-812/) forum. It says to put the code below into a "folder-level script", meaning in a folder such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\Javascripts`, called `sPrint.js`.

```
sPrint = app.trustedFunction(
    function(){
        app.beginPriv();
        this.print({bUI:false, bSilent:true, bShrinkToFit:false});
        app.endPriv();
    }
)
```

Then, and this is where the rub comes in, I have to change the JavaScript that gets injected to call this new `sPrint()` instead of just `print()` like it does now.

**Question**

Where can I change the JavaScript that Maximo injects into Direct Print PDFs? Is it stored in a .js file somewhere and the Java just copies it in? What file? Or is it hard-coded in the Java? Which class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe 8.1.2, you can upgrade your adobe reader client to 9.4 or 9.5 and this will resolve this issue.

Comment: We are on Reader 10.0, going to 11.0.15. But, thanks for the suggestion.